# Multicast call hangs up after 30 seconds

Tags: sip, linphone, linphone-sdk

I tried making multicast to work on **3.3.2** version and I don't know if this is a bug in linphone.
(If I make a normal call with this disabled below it works normally)

What I did was enabled, on Linphone service initialization

```
LinphoneManager.getLc().enableAudioMulticast(true);
LinphoneManager.getLc().setAudioMulticastAddr("224.0.0.100");
```

I make a call from
.4.12(IP) 102(PBX number) to .4.26(IP) 116(PBX number) device
(On 102 I am calling SIP number 116)

Call then works normally, and if I check in Wireshark I see that

**4.12** - Sending data over UDP to 224.0.0.100

**4.26** - Starts sending STUN Binding Request after 15 seconds, and is sending it once each second till the call stops

This is all that is going on, and then after 30 seconds call just ends.

On receiving end, on 4.26, I also tried adding

```
params.enableAudioMulticast(true);
```

but nothing changes

***Questions:***

1. Why does this call drop after 30 seconds? Do I have to enable something else, because I don't see this anywhere in documentation
2. How can I make all devices, which are listening on 224.0.0.100 to receive the call? If I make a call from 102 - 116, how can for example device, which is registered on 120, has multicast enabled, also receive this call? Should I make a call somehow differently?

Comment: 30 seconds sounds like a typical timeout value for a switch to terminate a multicast flow if there is nobody subscribed to it any more. You need to get in touch with your IT department and check that IGMP on the switch is configured correctly. This has nothing to do with programming, though.

Comment: Ok thank you! Will check into this

Comment: As I see this solution is for problem 1., but I don't see a reason why Linphone wouldn't automatically connect on multicast IP on all devices and why all devices don't receive the call, that are listening on it?